# Problem with Question Involving Magnets and Magnetic Fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

I don't understand in the following problem how the different components of x and y are negative and positive of the magnetic field. The question is: **The figure below shows 2 bar magnets of the same size and the same strength. Which of the arrows labeled A to D correctly represents the direction of the magnetic field at a point located at the common origin of the arrows? (That point is at an equal distance from the two magnets.)** There is a picture I will post that will accompany the question. If anyone could explain why the answer the direction A graphically that would be greatly appreciated. I don't understand how the x and y components of each are found but I do understand that the x component cancels out. Thanks in advance!

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP91O.jpg)

Comment: Just sketch a bunch of field lines.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: Consider a field line going from the right hand north pole through the “origin” and finishing on the right hand south pole remembering that the pattern of field lines is also symmetrical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much of an artist, but here goes:

Imagine that one magnet has blue field lines, and the other has red lines. Since they are facing the opposite ways, these must be going in the opposite direction.

[image: Field lines drawn out]

Now pick two field lines that are equal and opposite, both going through the point of interest. The fields will cancel in the B-D direction since the blue field points in the B direction, and the red in the D direction. However, they are both going upwards in the A direction, and so there will be a net magnetic field in that direction.

[image: Field lines meeting]

Comment: This is not very helpful. A hypothetical test North pole between the ends of the bar magnets, how would it move?

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor pictures. I believe the OP's question related to the field at the intersection of his axis, which is what I tried to answer. However, the same logic applies to a point midway between the end of the bar magnets, and the field goes straight up. There are no magnetic monopoles, but a small bar magnet placed there and free to spin would align itself with its north pole pointing upwards (in the A direction).

Comment: Yes. a test dipole would be aligned with the field lines in the direction A by the torque. But the force on it (or on a piece of iron) would along D (the gradient of the field).